# Add same random class on refresh to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, addclass

After a random class being added to elements and it changing on each refresh.

The following works, but i need it to be the same class for each element not random within it.

```
var classes = ["yellow", "pink", "green"];

$("body,#container,.site-header").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
});
```

The class is added to body, #container and .site-header as it should, but they are all different ones.

So... body, #container and .site-header should all have yellow, or all have pink etc changing on refresh.

```
body.pink
#container.pink
.site-header.pink
```

Currently body will have yellow, #container pink etc which is not what i’m after see...

```
body.pink
#container.yellow
.site-header.green
```

Comment: can you also put a tag as to what you are using for the uestion? From teh code I GUESS its javascript / jquery but the appropriate tag would help greatly in finding ppl to respond who know that language good enough

Answer (score 3):

I’ve figured it out myself, if anyone needs it..

```
var classes = ['purple','green', 'yellow', 'pink'];
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length);

$('body,#container,.site-header').addClass(classes[randomnumber]);
```